# Sql time difference calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have the following data

```
View_Start  View_End
5:00:00 AM   8:59:59 AM
5:00:00 AM   8:59:59 AM
5:00:00 AM   8:59:59 AM
19:00:00 PM  23:59:59 PM
12:00:00 AM  1:59:59 AM
2:00:00 AM   4:59:59 AM
```

I need to find difference of time between two column taking into consideration AM and PM,
I am doing this in sql

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL , SSMS workbench

Comment: Datediff function? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: What is the data type of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(hh, CAST(View_End AS TIME(0))) -
  DATEPART(hh, CAST(View_Start AS TIME(0))) AS Hours,
  DATEPART(mi, CAST(View_End AS TIME(0))) -
  DATEPART(mi, CAST(View_Start AS TIME(0))) AS Minutes,
  DATEPART(ss, CAST(View_End AS TIME(0))) -
  DATEPART(ss, CAST(View_Start AS TIME(0))) AS Seconds
FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
| Hours | Minutes | Seconds |
|-------|---------|---------|
|     3 |      59 |      59 |
|     3 |      59 |      59 |
|     3 |      59 |      59 |
|     4 |      59 |      59 |
|     1 |      59 |      59 |
|     2 |      59 |      59 |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9c4b/9)

Caveat: I see that you are using AM/PM notation with 24 hour time. The example I've provided will only be accurate for 24 hour time. If you are using 12 hour time, you will need a fancier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  SELECT convert(varchar(2),FORMAT(DATEDIFF(s, @startDate, @endDate)/3600,'0#'))+':'
           +convert(varchar(2),FORMAT(DATEDIFF(s, @startDate, @endDate)%3600/60,'0#'))+':'
           +convert(varchar(2),FORMAT(DATEDIFF(s, @startDate, @endDate)%60,'0#')) AS Duration
```